# Ajax call to PHP script returning status 0 after double refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I had a simple form that used JQuery AJAX to call a PHP script and perform some work. This code worked properly for 2+ years and then all the sudden stopped working - and has some weird behavior I've having trouble debugging.

Here's the HTML code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="commenter-name" class="col-sm-3">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="commenter-name" id="commenter-name" placeholder="Enter Name" value="" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="commenter-comment" class="col-sm-3">Comment</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="commenter-comment" id="commenter-comment" placeholder="Enter Comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="form-group custom-form">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input id="submit-comment" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the JS code (using JQuery 1.8.3):

```
$("#submit-comment").click(function(event) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
          url: "_code/ProcessPoll.php",
          data: { comment : comment,  name : name, commenter_position : commenter_position }
      })
});
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
if ($_POST["comment"])
{
        //log results of the poll
        $log = new PollsLogging($_POST["name"], $_POST["comment"], "comment", "comment", $_POST["commenter_position"]);
        $log->WriteToFile();
}
```

This code worked effectively for 2+ years and now this is the behavior:

> 1. Enter info in the textbox fields and hit the submit button
> 2. The click event is triggered and then the JQuery AJAX call is made, but does not bring back a completion, success, or failure (I'm using the debugger in
>      Chrome)
> 3. Then I refresh the page and I am getting a status of 0 in the error from the AJAX (I don't have the debugging in here, but I just used
>      this to figure it out: error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(jqXHR.status)}

Could something have changed in the different versions of all the major browsers for this to stop working? Am I blatantly missing something? I read a few things about the AJAX call might never be completing, but I'm not sure how to handle that... especially since I haven't made any code changes to this... I also have a few other small programs that are similar and those have also stopped working and are behaving in a similar way!

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the _ from the url

Comment: Just tried it. Same behavior.

Comment: Are you using a jQuery CDN or have you hosted your jQuery file locally? Try using an older version of jQuery to see if the problem is with jQuery itself.

Comment: I've tried multiple versions of JQuery (from 1.3.0 all the way to the latest). No luck yet. I've even stripped down the code to just run the AJAX call when the page loads and call a PHP script that just does a sleep(1000); - and still getting the same behavior.

Comment: I've also tried this on multiple servers...

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I can't comment because of my poor reputation, so I post this as an answer.

Actually, it's not possible to provide you an answer, we lack informations.
I don't see any problem in the code you presented.

You're talking about a strange behaviour, can you describe it ?
Did you tried to use a tool like Firebug to monitor your request headers ?